# div layering with selective scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have 3 DIVs (placed in this order on the page):

```
<div id="one">
    <button id="newButton"></button>
</div>
<div id="two">
    <table id="tableHeader"></table>
</div>
<div id="three">
    <table id="tableBody"></table>
</div>
```

DIV "One" and DIV "Two" I do not want these to be scroll-able vertically. I want both to remain displayed when scrolling vertically.

DIV "One" I want it to be frozen horizontally so when you scroll left to right it remain in the center of the screen.

DIV "Two" which is the table header. I want it to scroll horizontally with the table body.

DIV "three" which is the table body i want to be scroll-able vertically and horizontally.

For DIVs Two and three i have already figured out how to align the header and body columns using JScript so that not an issue it is just the issues with the scrolling and freezing of DIVs One and two.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set up custom jquery events for each div to check the status of the other divs:
https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: Can this not occur with pure CSS?

Comment: Maybe.. Your requirements seem pretty complex, so doing it with only css will be tricky.